# Open System Status Menu from terminal

Tags: shortcut-keys, interface

I'm looking for a command to open this menu and bind it to the right Win key.
[image]

Comment: In the terminal `man bash-builtins`. when the page loads, type `\bind` or just scroll down. If this helps, let me know and I will add an answer.

Comment: according to the manpage, `bind -X "\e-m":ls` should set `[Esc]` + `[m]` to the `ls` command (just to test functionality), but all it did for me is break the enter key in that terminal instance. Anyone have any idea why or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Oh yeah, you cn set key combos in the main menu! I completely forgot. It is toward the bottom. You will know it when you see it.

Comment: @UnKNOWn
Thank you, the answer you gave me was the correct one.